# LINQ adding mystery "+1" to my int's in generated SQL

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I have to admit, I am just plan stumped....I have the below LINQ to SQL Method -->

```
    public static int GetLastInvoiceNumber(int empNumber)
    {
        using (var context = CmoDataContext.Create())
        {
            context.Log = Console.Out;

            IQueryable<tblGreenSheet> tGreenSheet = context.GetTable<tblGreenSheet>();
            return (tGreenSheet
                            .Where(gs => gs.InvoiceNumber.Substring(3, 4) == empNumber.ToString())
                            .Max(gs => Convert.ToInt32(gs.InvoiceNumber.Substring(7, gs.InvoiceNumber.Length)))
                            );
        }
    }
```

This was made based from a SQL query written by a co-worker to achieve *nearly* the same thing -->

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
SUBSTRING([InvoiceNumber], 1, 6) AS EmpNumber,
MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING([InvoiceNumber], 7, LEN([InvoiceNumber])) AS INT)) AS MaxInc
FROM [CMO].[dbo].[tblGreenSheet]
WHERE SUBSTRING([InvoiceNumber], 3, 4) = '1119' --EmployeeNumber
GROUP BY SUBSTRING([InvoiceNumber], 1, 6)
```

However, the SQL that is being generated, when I check through `context.Log = Console.Out` is this-->

```
SELECT MAX([t1].[value]) AS [value]
FROM (
    SELECT CONVERT(Int,SUBSTRING([t0].[InvoiceNumber], @p0 + 1, LEN([t0].[InvoiceNumber]))) AS [value], [t0].[InvoiceNumber]
    FROM [dbo].[tblGreenSheet] AS [t0]
    ) AS [t1]
WHERE SUBSTRING([t1].[InvoiceNumber], @p1 + 1, @p2) = @p3
-- @p0: Input Int (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [7]
-- @p1: Input Int (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [3]
-- @p2: Input Int (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [4]
-- @p3: Input VarChar (Size = 4; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [1119]
```

You can see that it is actually fairly close with the **GLARING** exception of some added `+1`'s!!!

**WTH?!?**

I even verified that it WOULD be correct by removing the `+1`'s in the generated SQL and running it with it generating the same results as the original SQL.

So, what am I missing or doing wrong?  Is this a well know *LOL* of LINQ's to screw with us less talented programmers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL Server's SUBSTRING uses 1-based indexing, whereas `string.Substring` uses zero-based indexing. The `+ 1` maps between the bases to preserve the C# semantics.

As to why you had to remove the `+ 1` to make it work correctly, that's a mystery to me.

Comment: I see... but the LINQ version doesn't work at all.  It try's to return NULL as there aren't any matches. but I know there are as the SQL version works and the LINQ / SQL Dump works without the +1's

Answer (score 2):

@MarceloCantos answer is correct, but here is the explanation as to why it works when you remove the `+ 1`:

You have converted 
`SUBSTRING([InvoiceNumber], 3, 4)` to `gs.InvoiceNumber.Substring(3, 4)` but since C# uses zero-based index you should actually use `gs.InvoiceNumber.Substring(2, 4)` to start at the third character.

Similarly you should use `gs.InvoiceNumber.Substring(6)` as the substitution for `SUBSTRING([InvoiceNumber], 7, LEN([InvoiceNumber]))`. Note that there is no need to specify the length of the substring in C# if you want all that is after the index. Actually `gs.InvoiceNumber.Substring(7, gs.InvoiceNumber.Length)` would cause an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` if you tried to use it separately, but now that it is  translated to T-SQL it actually works.

On a side note `SUBSTRING([InvoiceNumber], 1, 6) AS EmpNumber` seems to indicate that it the first six characters are the `EmployeeNumber` but you are only looking at the last four of them. Presumably because you only have < 10000 Employees at the moment, but this might come back to bite you later.

I would suggest you break out the methods above and give them proper names, to enhance readability. E.g. `getEmployeeNumber(string invoiceNumber)`, etc.